# Changing a content on touch event in famo.us

Tags: javascript, famo.us

I am trying to make a simple Surface that would change it's content on a registered touch event. Here is a snippet:

```
var mySurface = new Surface({
    content: ''
});

mySurface.on('touchstart', function() {
    this.setContent('Hello World!');
});
```

The problem I have is that the string 'Hello World!' appears only when I move my finger on the screen. It feels like it is firing on a `touchmove` event, instead of a `touchstart` event. In fact, both of them provide the same result to me. When I emulate an Android phone in Chrome, then it works properly - `touchstart` fires as soon as I "touch" a button. When I open the page on a real device, then `touchstart` doesn't fire and behaves as `touchmove`.
I also checked a Famo.us demo example "Taasky". It has a "DELETE" button with `touchstart` event and the problem is same - in Chrome emulator it works properly, but on a real device nothing happens when I touch the display, and it fires when I start moving the finger sideways.

**EDIT:**
Tested with Samsung Galaxy S3 - fires when I start moving finger sideways.
Tested with iPhone5 - fires on `touchstart`, as expected.

Comment: whats the "real" device?  have you checked on multiple devices?

Comment: Added tested devices: Samsung Galaxy S3 and iPhone5.

Comment: Can you file this as a github issue here https://github.com/famous/famous/issues ?

Comment: Sure, Andrew. Will do.